# how to assert mock state simultaneous with thrown exception

Tags: c#, tdd, moq

I'm following TDD and ran into a problem where if I make one test succeed, two others fail due to an exception being thrown.  Well, I want to throw the exception, but I also want to verify the other behaviors.  For instance:

```
public class MyTests {

    [Fact]
    public void DoSomethingIsCalledOnceWhenCheckerIsTrue() 
    {
        var checker = new Mock<IChecker>();
        var doer = new Mock<IDoer>();

        checker.Setup(x => x.PassesCheck).Returns(true);
        var sut = new ThingThatChecksAndDoes(checker.Object,doer.Object);

        sut.CheckAndDo();

        checker.VerifyGet(x => x.PassesCheck, Times.Once());
        doer.Verify(x => x.Do(),Times.Once());
    }

    [Fact]
    public void DoSomethingIsNeverCalledWhenCheckerIsFalse() 
    {
        var checker = new Mock<IChecker>();
        var doer = new Mock<IDoer>();

        checker.Setup(x => x.PassesCheck).Returns(false);
        var sut = new ThingThatChecksAndDoes(checker.Object,doer.Object);

        sut.CheckAndDo();

        doer.Verify(x => x.Do(),Times.Never());
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ThrowCheckDidNotPassExceptionWhenCheckDoesNotPass()
    {
        var checker = new Mock<IChecker>();
        var doer = new Mock<IDoer>();

        checker.Setup(x => x.PassesCheck).Returns(false);
        var sut = new ThingThatChecksAndDoes(checker.Object,doer.Object);

        Assert.Throws<CheckDidNotPassException>(() => { sut.CheckAndDo(); });
    }

}
```

**What are my choices for approaching this?  What, if any, would be the "preferred" choice?**

Answer (score 1):

Your 1st and 2nd test passes. Then when you add the 3rd test the rest of the tests fails!.

With TDD

> "Avoid altering existing tests that pass. Instead, add new tests.
>   Change existing tests only when the user requirements change."

I also assume your SUT (System Under Test) as below

```
  public void CheckAndDo() {
        var b = _checker.PassesCheck;
        if (b) {
            _doer.Do();
        }

        throw new CheckDidNotPassException();
    }
```

In your SUT, when you throw a new exception, obviously it has an effect on the rest of the behaviour the way you have implemented execution logic.

So the option here would be to change the existing test(s).

Give it a well named test method, and Assert both exception and the verification.

```
    [Test]
    public void CheckAndDo_WhenPassesCheckTrue_DoCalledOnlyOnceAndThrowsCheckDidNotPassException()
    {
        var checker = new Mock<IChecker>();
        var doer = new Mock<IDoer>();

        checker.Setup(x => x.PassesCheck).Returns(true);
        var sut = new ThingThatChecksAndDoes(checker.Object, doer.Object);

        Assert.Throws<CheckDidNotPassException>(() => { sut.CheckAndDo(); });
        doer.Verify(x => x.Do(), Times.Once());
    }
```

Few other things you need to consider:

a. TDD produces good Unit tests. Good means, readable, maintainable and trustworthy Unit Tests.
   Your test method names and the calls to SUT are poorly named. I guess this is just for the demo/Stackoverflow question. But I suggest in future you provide a real world example with real names other than "Do" "Something"
   Having ambiguous names does not help from the TDD point of view as you are designing your system in small based on the requirements.

b. Publish the correct code.
In your first test you passing Mock types

```
   var checker = new Mock<IChecker>();
   var doer = new Mock<IDoer>();
   var sut = new ThingThatChecksAndDoes(checker, doer);
```

You should pass the instances i.e (checker.Object)

Answer (score 0):

When I test similar methods

- I do not write a test, that x.Do() is not called
- I check that exception is thrown and x.Do() is not called in one test because these two Assertions are related to the same flow.